# Problema menu colapsable bootstrap

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Estoy creando un link colapsable en mi barra de navegación para que el usuario acceda a sus preferencias, cerrar sesión etc.

El ejemplo lo tomé [de aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-left&stacked=h), con algunas modificaciones.

Intenté que el menú se muestre flotante a la izquierda de la pantalla y por más opciones de Bootstrap que coloque no sucede.

Debería verse así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en mi caso se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Honestamente creo que se ve mejor hacia abajo, pero el **verdadero problema es que al hacer clic me crea un *scroll* en el ancho de la pantalla**.

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row navbar-murulu">
        <div class="col-10 navbarbrand">
          <div class="logo-murulu">
            <img class="logo-imagen-mascotas img-fluid" src="./imagenes/logo-murulu-mascotas.png" alt="Logo de Mürülü">
            <img class="logo-m img-fluid" src="./imagenes/logo-murulu-texto.png" alt="Logo Mürülü">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 navbaruserprofile">
          <div class="avartar-userprofile">
            <!-- Nav menu with user information -->
            <nav class="navbar dropdown dropleft float-right">
              <div class="dropdown ml-auto">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-user dropdown-toggle media align-items-center" data-toggle="dropdown" data-sidebar="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-2.jpg" class="rounded-circle z-depth-0 profile-picture" alt="avatar image" width="40" height="40">
                  <div class="user-name">
                    Luna medina
                  </div>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" role="menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Preferencias</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Cerrar sesión</a>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Funciona bien a pesar de que el div con `ml-auto` estorba. Seguramente una hoja de estilo que no vemos provoca ese efecto.

Comment: Desactive mis 2 hojas de estilo, comenté casi todo  mi código a excepción del menú y el problema persiste, si es con algún estilo en especifico será algo propio de bootstrap pero no logro verlo.

Comment: Al igual que sal lo he probado y funciona correctamente, debe de ser algún estilo no estas viendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, sal, @luisam - ya estoy revisando a fondo que estilo me está ocasionando el problema.

Comment: Al final si encontré el error, al inicio del  <meta> estaba cargando una librería de bootstrap 4.0.0 por error. Gracias a todos